# Clearcase UCM: How different foundation baselines affect merging between streams

Tags: merge, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We employ a model where we have on integration and one common development stream per UCM project. Project A is the trunk. Project B is a branch of project A created on baseline BL1 of the integration stream of project A. The development stream of project A has been later rebased using using baseline BL2 in the integration stream. So BL2 is a newer baseline compared to BL1.

The question is would the fact the project's A development stream and project's B development stream now have different foundation baselines (with project's A dev stream having a newer foundation baseline) affect merging from project's B development stream to project's A development stream?

I understand that there would be a lot of non-tivial merges as the difference is quite big, but need to be sure there won't be any fundamental problems with CC in this situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would: it would be a **sideway merge**

You can see one side-effect in the question [ClearCase wants to merge unchanged files after deliver to alternate target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090911/clearcase-wants-to-merge-unchanged-files-after-deliver-to-alternate-target/1092659).

In your case though, the effect should be minimal:
Merging from B to A should not generate more conflicts than usual for modified files, except if those files (modified in B) are no  longer present in A (because rmnamed in BL2):
then a manual merge of the *parent directory* of those files would be needed.