# What is equivalent of "Clearcase Stream Attribute" in git

Tags: git, clearcase

We use ClearCase UCM and slowly switching to git.

We use ClearCase [attributes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkattr.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-32) heavily.  For example MailTo attribute added to a Stream. We query this and send emails in case build failure or SCM activity like new recommended baselines.

Is there a similar construct in git? What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two:

- the closest one is [`git notes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes), which can leaves an "note" attached to objects, without touching the objects themselves (meaning without modifying their SHA1).
  Attaching a note to a git tag is a bit similar to [add an attributes to an UCM baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2400864/6309).
  See more in "[notes to self](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/08/25/notes.html)".
- the other is [git branch description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858853/6309) (but, as [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/733345/joe) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514317/what-is-equivalent-of-clearcase-stream-attribute-in-git/28514335#comment45346615_28514335), that description isn't pushed to a remote repo)

  ```
  git branch --edit-description
  ```

> can be used to add descriptive text
>      to explain what a topic branch is about.

Comment: To add context from another of your answers, note that [branch descriptions aren't pushed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998142/git-pushing-branch-descriptions-to-remote) to a remote repository (but [notes can be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268986/git-how-to-push-messages-added-by-git-notes-to-the-central-git-server)).

Comment: @Joe true, I have included your comment in the answer.