# Is it possible to create a development stream with specific moules from baseline in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

Is it possible to create a development stream with specific modules from baseline in clearcase ?

Scenario:

Integration stream baseline contains around 20 modules, out of them we wanted to have only 4 modules as part of new development stream.  Is it possible to create development stream with specific modules from a baseline?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is: when you create a stream, it is empty by default.

If you are using the GUI (UCM project explorer), the new dev stream might have components if there are recommended baselines on the integration stream (in which case you can remove the extra components)

But if you are using the CLI (that is 'cleartool', the command line interface), you will create an empty stream, and you will rebase it with only the four baselines of the four components you want.
Use [`cleartool mkstream`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkstream.htm):

```
cleartool mkstream -in YourIntStream@\yourPVob YourDevStream@\yourPVob
```

You can see example of stream (and view creation and rebase) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091075/6309).
But once the stream is created (and empty), you can rebase it through the GUI.
If it has components (because of recommended baselines), you also can remove the extra components through the GUI.