# Lost Checked In changes in ClearCase

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

In Clearcase I have version tree A---->B---->C.

I created a snapshot view on B and made few changes.
I did a check out and check in.

I rebased my branch to C and again to B.
Now I am not able to see my changes.

Is there any way I can get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Version tree" represents the versions of a file.
"rebasing a branch" means A, B and C are not version but branches, or potentially UCM streams.

In any case, check if you can see your changes by calling the actual version tree on a file you know you have modified (version tree similar to the [ones you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1092659/6309))
Do a couple of "compare with previous" on some versions to see if you can find back your changes and understand why the LATEST version on B is not the one with the content you expect.

Comment: I opened the History Browser for one file I changed and I am able to see the changes there, but do you know any way I can merge those changes back to my branch.

Comment: @Gaurav Right click on that version (in the version tree), select "merge to", point to the current version (the one with an eye on it): that will checkout and merge. Check-in and you have created a new version.