# Issue with deliver vs rebase in clearcase ucm

Tags: rebase, clearcase-ucm

I am in a confusion here on UCM rebase vs deliver. So, I have a parent stream A and two child streams B and C taken from different baselines of parent stream.Now, I have delivered from stream B to Stream A and created a new baseline. Now, I tried to rebase stream C and I got very few elements to merge. Whereas , If I deliver from B to C , I get many elements to merge. Why is this so? should both not be same as the changes from B are already delivered to A?

Answer (score 0):

> should both not be same as the changes from `B` are already delivered to `A`?

No, because of the common ancestor which changes:

- deliver `B` to `A`, then rebase `C`: the common ancestor and the source of the rebase are the same: the new baseline created on `A` (result of the deliver)
- deliver `B` to `C` directly: the common ancestor remains a baseline on A, different from `B` (source) and `C` (destination).
  That is not changed by the fact that `B` was also delivered to `A` and a new baseline was created on `A`.

I would recommend, for any new merge you see in the second deliver case, to open a version tree, like I did in "[ClearCase wants to merge unchanged files after deliver to alternate target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1092659/6309)". You will see which version is merge to where, and deduce why that version was considered for said merge.

Comment: I get it . But then what is the use of rebase here which is not solving my purpose of bringing changes of B(which are already delivered to A) into C?

Comment: @user2636464 the benefit is only to make C like A, meaning like the baseline create on A and showing the result of B merged to A. Check if B modifications are visible in C view now (they might not need a merge)

Comment: So, I did rebase C and it merged some files into C.But, It did not get all changes from B into C, although the changes are already there in A.I wonder how can i fix that so I have all changes from B into C.

Comment: @user2636464 When you did rebase C, did you use a baseline created on A?

Comment: Yes I rebased c after b was delivered to A. So yes using baseline on A

Comment: @user2636464 In that case, that should have changed the foundation baseline of C (direct sub-stream of A), making B files (merged into that baseline from A by the intial deliver) visible. Are B files visible in that A baseline?

Comment: sorry for the late response. yes B files are visible in A.